# Richfaces server side pagination without session scope

Tags: jsf, pagination, richfaces

I am implementing server side pagination using Richfaces, but the implementation using PaginatingDataModel requires bean to be saved in SessionScope. Using JSF 2.0, RichFaces 4.4. Refer URL below:

http://katzmaier.blogspot.in/2010/03/richfaces-server-side-pagination.html
https://community.jboss.org/thread/204250

Is there any alternate implementation to implement server side pagination using request scope?
By server side pagination, I mean data for each page to be fetched by executing queries instead of retrieving all records at once.

Comment: Have you tried ViewScoped ?

Comment: If you're using JSF 2 + RichFaces 4, then you can try using a `@ViewScoped` managed bean. If you're using JSF 1.2 + RichFaces 3.x, you can add the `@KeepAlive` annotation to your request scoped managed bean class in order to make it live while the user is still in the same view.

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie that won't work if OP uses JSF 1.2 (by the question, it looks like OP's not using JSF 2).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, yes, I was hoping the OP has upgraded since JSF 2.0 has major benefits :)

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie not everyone can upgrade from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.0 for different restrictions i.e. web application server is Java EE 5 compliant, and our answers should help OP with what he/she currently works.

Comment: A lot of what Katz put up there was unreadable and all mashed up together, but layman's web design states that for any case where variables are supposed to survive requests and you don't have the luxury of a session, simply stash whatever variables you desire in the request object and retrieve the values in your destination.

Comment: @AlexandreLavoie: Thanks. ViewScope solved the issue. Please add this as answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered in comment, you could use the `ViewScoped` instead of `SessionScoped`. This is a new scope available since JSF 2.0, perfect to keep data server side for a shorter time.

Here is a link of a blog talking about new features in JSF 2.0 [What's new in JSF 2.0](http://andyschwartz.wordpress.com/2009/07/31/whats-new-in-jsf-2/)